# Dúvida nas relações do Eloquent - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde desculpe se deixei passar alguma pergunta similar, busquei exaustivamente tanto aqui quanto no inglês e não achei nada parecido,

possuo o seguinte Modelo no banco de dados

```
contract
   id
   due_date

contract_service
   id
   price
   contract_id
   type_id

service
   id 
   name
   desc
   base_price
```

Os modelos são Contract, ContractService, Service, segue os respectivos relacionamentos:

```
class Contract extends Model
{
    public function service() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ContractService');
    }
}

class ContractService extends Model
{    
    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Service', 'type_id');
    }
}

class Service extends Model
{    

}
```

No laravel eu busco o nome dos serviços do contrato dessa maneira (por ser hasMany)

```
$contract->service[0]->type->name
```

Existe alguma maneira deu reduzir essa relação extensa e fazer algo do tipo abaixo?

```
$contract->service[0]->name
```

A tabela service é onde guardo o tipo dos Serviços a serem prestados, seria algo como conctract_service_description (que o OpenCart utiliza usando inner_join se não me engano).

Comment: Qual são os relacionamentos? Descreva na perguntas...

Comment: É assim mesmo, Cassiano. Se for fazer Join não precisa dos relacionamentos no Model.

Comment: Se você fizer um `join` na busca ficará como você está solicitando.

Comment: Coloquei os models

Comment: Acho que não precisa de um `JOIN` não.  Você pode usar `hasManyThrought`.

Comment: O hasManyThrough não funciona pra esse caso, deveria ser algo do tipo hasManyThroughBelongsTo. Encontrei uma discussão que resolveu esse problema, segue o link: http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many 

Vlw pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução no fórum do Laravel mesmo, mas é algo que não faz parte do core do framework.

A resposta já está ancorada pelo link. Nela há a explicação de como implementar a nova relação HasManyThroughBelongsTo que responde a minha dúvida: http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many?page=1#reply-25585